# Finding out the validity of the electrolysis of CaS to Ca(OH)2 to S in alkaline electrolyte

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry

I would like to ask for the advice of chemists on how to go about validating a reaction that I have hypothesized as one stage in a chemical plant I am trying to improve. I want to find out whether a solution of CalciumSulfide (CaS) in an aqueous solution of high pH electrolyzes into solid CalciumHydroxide ( Ca(OH)2 ) and solid (monoclinic) sulfur ( S ). From datapages (wikipedia and chem-libretexts) on electrode potentials, I have determined that the most probable outcome of subjecting this electrolyte to a (absolute) voltage of about 0.4 V yields the production of hydroxide ions (along with hydrogen gas) at the kathode and the oxidation of sulfur anions at the anode (under the assumption that [OH-]~[S-2]~1 M). My hypothesis (and the necessary condition for my proposal to work) is that the hydroxide from the kathode reacts with the Ca(OH)+ in the electrolyte to form calcium hydroxide precipitate settling at the bottom of the electrolyte vessel, and that the sulfur (upon oxidation) leaches to the anode as a (monoclinic) crystalline solid. This would mean that the two products can be extracted separately in somewhat pure form, and I would be a happy man.

Half-reactions:

**2H2O(l) + 2e − → H2(g) + 2OH−(aq) (−0.829 V)**

**S −2 (aq) → S(s) + 2e − (+0.407 V)**

Total reaction:

**2 H2O(l) + S −2 (aq) + Ca+2(aq) → H2(g) + S(s) + Ca(OH)2(s) (−0.422 V)**

I have not studied chemistry (physics rather), but I still want to find out whether this reaction takes place under the above voltaic potential difference (so as to confirm my belief of the power consumption to be ∆G = n · F · epsilon_0 = −2 · 96, 485 · 0.422 kJ/mol = ~80 kJ/mol(S, Ca(OH)2, H2) )

I have two ways of finding out:

Does any of you chemists reading this know (a) if this reaction takes place under steady-state pH~12-14 (b) if this the only reaction to take place under steady-state pH~12-14, and (c) if this reaction takes place under the above-mentioned potential difference of epsilon_0 = 0.4 V?

In case I have to do the experiment myself in order to confirm my hypothesis would this cause me any problems? Namely, I will either (a) buy pure CaS from the internet, or (b) buy CaO and S from the internet, then produce H2 from hydrolysis myself and combine H2+S+CaO -> CaS + H2O under high temperature. Having obtained CaS through either option, I will dissolve CaS under constant stirring and under electrolysis at various voltages in order to document the molar quantities of the products from some energy investment. My problem (especially with option b) is that it is not legal for me to buy these chemicals. Remember, I do not have any degree or license in chemistry so this might raise eyebrows with law enforcement, which I do not want.

Thank you for reading. I hope this explained my situation well enough.

Comment: The trouble is that calcium sulfide $\ce{CaS}$ is not soluble in water. It is contained in the mineral called oldhamite. It cannot be electrolyzed in water.